# RabbitMQ: starting the server

Tags: rabbitmq

I downloaded rabbitmq on my mac via homebrew. Following these instructions I added sbin to path then called:

$ rabbitmq-server

and got the following error:

```
    BOOT FAILED
    ===========

```
Error description:
   {error,
       {cannot_delete_plugins_expand_dir,
           ["/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand",
            {cannot_delete,
                 "/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand/amqp_client-3.3.2/ebin/amqp_auth_mechanisms.beam",
            eacces}]}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit_plugins,prepare_plugins,3,
                  [{file,"src/rabbit_plugins.erl"},{line,123}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-1-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,332}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,354}]},
    {init,start_it,1,[]},
    {init,start_em,1,[]}]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{error {cannot_delete_plugins_expand_dir,["/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost plugins-expand",{cannot_delete,"/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand/amqp_client-3.3.2/ebin/amqp_auth_mechanisms.beam",eacces}]}}}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Anyone encounter this error before?

Comment: Try using `sudo rabbit-server`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me - sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/

Comment: This directory may contain durable messages and may result in data loss.

Answer (score 6):

another option is to try with `sudo rabbitmq-server` to launch server with correct user permissions

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem, it should be caused by the access error

[image]

you just need to change the access to the rabbitmq user.
then it worked.

```
 chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@l-pg/msg_store_transient
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check permissions:

```py
sudo chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/
```